# Undefined reference to `yylex'

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to parse one input file using flex and bison but I am facing one difficulty while compiling my program. I am attaching my flex and bison code and error which I am getting.

Please help me out to solve these errors

**lex.l**

```
%{
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <stdio.h>
#include "yacc.tab.h"
 #define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()

using namespace std;  


%}

DOT             "."  
COLON           ":"  
SEMICOLON       ";"  
COMMA           ","  
ANGLE_LEFT      "<"  
ANGLE_RIGHT     ">"  
AT              "@"  
EQUAL           "="  
SQUARE_OPEN     "["  
SQUARE_CLOSE    [^\\]"]"  
OPENBRACE       "\("  
CLOSEBRACE      "\)"  
QUOTE           "\""  
QUOTE_OPEN      "\""  
QUOTE_CLOSE     [^\\]"\""  
SPACE           " "  
TAB             "\t"  
CRLF            "\r\n"  
QUOTED_PAIR     "\\"[^\r\n]  
DIGIT           [0-9]  
ALPHA           [a-zA-Z]  
QTEXT           [0-9a-zA-Z!#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]  

%%

[a-zA-Z0-9]+            { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return TOK_STRING; }

{SPACE}*                    {return TOK_SPACE; }

{SPACE}*Name.*              {return TOK_NAME; }  
{SPACE}*SIZE.*              {return TOK_SIZE; }  
{SPACE}*ITERATE.*           {return TOK_ITERATE; }  
{SPACE}*DIRECTION.*     {return TOK_DIRECTION; }  

^{CRLF}                         { return TOK_EMPTY_LINE; }  
{CRLF}                          {}  
.                               {}/* ignore unknown chars */
```

**yacc.y**

```
 %{
 #include <cstdio> 
 #include <cstring>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();  
extern "C" FILE *yyin;

void yyerror(const char* s);  


%}

%union  
{  
    char* sval;  
};  

%token <sval> TOK_NAME  
%token <sval> TOK_SIZE  
%token <sval> TOK_STRING  
%token <sval> TOK_ITERATE  
%token <sval> TOK_DIRECTION  


%token TOK_SPACE  


%%

str:  
    TOK_SPACE TOK_NAME TOK_SPACE TOK_STRING   
    {  
        cout << "Value:" << $2 << "->" << $4;  
    }  
    ;  
%%  

int main(void) {  
    FILE * pt = fopen("new file ", "r" );  
    if(!pt)  
    {  
    cout << "Bad Input.Noexistant file" << endl;  
    return -1;  
    }  
    yyin = pt;  
    do  
    {  
        yyparse();  
     }while (!feof(yyin));        
}  
void yyerror(const char *s)  
{  
   cout << "Error. " << s << endl;   
   exit(-1);     
}
```

I build these using:

```
flex bas.l 
bison -d yacc.y 
g++ lex.yy.c yacc.tab.c -lfl -o scanner.exe
```

While compiling program I found following errors:

> /tmp/cceIyDkD.o: In function `main':
>   yacc.tab.c:(.text+0x708): multiple definition of `main'
>   /tmp/ccatq95p.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0x1228): first defined here
>   /usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `main' changed from 86 in /tmp/ccatq95p.o to 120 in /tmp/cceIyDkD.o
>   /tmp/cceIyDkD.o: In function `yyparse()':
>   yacc.tab.c:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `yylex'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help me out

Comment: These are linker errors.  It would help if you showed your linker command.

Comment: flex bas.l  bison -d yacc.y  g++ lex.yy.c yacc.tab.c -lfl -o scanner.exe

Comment: What is the first line printed by the command `g++ --version`? I think you are probably using a very old compiler and that is causing some problems. (Also, your question says that your scanner file is called `lex.l`, but you invoke `flex bas.l`. I assume that was just a typo.)

Comment: I got the problem. Thank you so much for helping me out

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, it turns out that flex 2.6.x changed the way yylex behaves. I solved this problem by using an older version of Flex. In Ubuntu, there's this package called flex-old that is that older version. Replacing flex by flex-old solved this problem for me.

Comment: Thanks! Downgrading to the "flex-old" package was the solution for me too.

Comment: You're welcome! A good aspect of this solution is that it doesn't need to change your make file because both flex and flex-old are accessible by the flex command in the terminal.

Comment: It would be good to include a description of what changed in 2.6.x or at least include a link for those who would rather fix their code to work with the new version of flex.

Answer (score 3):

1. In parser.y, more precisely C part of the code where you include stuff, you need to write: `extern int yylex(void);`. Extern keyword is not needed, because global functions by default have dynamic connectivity, but it is good practice to write keyword to point that function is not from that file you're working. Your code has no mistake here however.
2. Compile lex.yy.c to the object file, compile y.tab.c to object file and then link them together in final program. *It is very important to first do `yacc` command, because Lex is using yacc.tab.h generated with Yacc.* You're getting error because you flex it, but you don't know what yacc.tab.h is.

   `yacc -d yacc.y` Make y.tab.c

   `g++ -c y.tab.c -o y.tab.o` Compile y.tab.c to object file y.tab.o

   `flex lex.l` Make lex.yy.c

   `g++ -c lex.yy.c -o lex.yy.o` Compile lex.yy.c to object file lex.yy.o

   `g++ lex.yy.o y.tab.o -o program` Link them together.

**Note:** Make sure that in your lex file you include "y.tab.h" after other includes, because it is possible that other includes use some function declared in y.tab.h, so have that in mind. Situations like this can occur when you're writing more complex parsers.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in the code which stop it from compiling. You need to add into the file **yacc.y**:

```
%token <sval> TOK_EMPTY_LINE
```

and at the end:

```
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

and build this way:

```
flex bas.l 
bison -d yacc.y 
g++ yacc.tab.c -lfl -o scanner.exe
```

You will find it now compiles.

You may want to note I removed a couple of typos in your lexer source in the question. Not all the the rules started in the first column. I removed a couple of leading spaces on  the basis that they were typos.

Comment: @shailavishah It compiles and runs on my system. Can you indicate what operating system and software you are running? It might help explain the different results.

Comment: bas.l: In function ���int main()���:
    bas.l:46: error: redefinition of ���int main()���
    yacc.y:40: error: ���int main()��� previously defined here

Comment: I found above error. My operating System is red hat and I am running it through command line.

Comment: @shailavishah What is the result of `g++ --version` as asked by @rici. This could also be related to the cause.... It can we solved when we have enough facts.

Comment: This line is added at the end of the yacc.y file

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)

Comment: ohk...I got the problem thank you so much for help me out

Comment: @shailavishah All solved? So pleased. Accept the answer if you have the solution.